# how to define workflow to run based on two push rules

Tags: github, github-actions, lerna

Is there a way to define 2 push rules in same workflow file or work around ?

How to combine and write below rules into single workflow file :

1. Run when any file is pushed on non master branch

```
On:
  push:
     branches-ignore:
     - 'master'
     paths:
     - 'path-to-package/**'
```

2. Run Only when particular(package.json) file pushed in master branch

```
On:
  push:
     branches:
     - 'master'
     paths:
     - 'path-to-package/package.json'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specific request doesn't appear to be supported by the syntax.

According to the workflow syntax for [GitHub Actions documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions), two trigger configurations appear unrelated.

*GitHub allows free users to open support requests. You could always make a feature request at [support.github.com/contact](https://support.github.com/contact)*

The closest workaround I know at the moment would be something like the workflow below, using a conditional inside your jobs.

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'path-to-package/package.json'

jobs:
  build_pom:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo 'this is master'
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
```

Comment: hey thanks for the work around and suggestion. But only thing i am concerned with is We have around 30+ packages so this work around will still run all the workflows and pollute all workflow runs.

Comment: You can create one workflow to check the packages and the branch, and another workflow (triggered by a `dispatch` event from the first one) to perform what you want to do when the condition is met. The first one will always trigger, but the second one will only trigger when you configure it to. It is not the best solution, but until having a specific feature for it, it's still a possible workaround :)